# Solubility of epinephrine in water

Tags: solubility, aromatic-compounds, amines

Do you know how can I dissolve epinephrine in water? because it is insoluble in ordinary situation. When I decreased the pH by $\ce{HCl}$ it really worked but I need pH=7 to continue my experiment. Can I add $\ce{HCl}$ and dissolve the EPI and later using buffer to reach pH=7 and in this way the EPI wont be precipitate?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you have any questions about the site you can take the short [tour] or visit the [help]. It might me easier to help you if you stated your end goal, or at least what you need to do after it's dissolved.

Answer (score 2):

What the context of aiming for a highly concentrated aqueous solution of epinephrine / adrenaline?  What would be a sufficient concentration?  Would -- assuming a chemical reaction is intended -- in sight of a low reaction rate a steady of epinephrine in low concentration be sufficient?

While [this](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/epinephrine#section=Top) lists a typical concentration of saturation in water of about 180 mg/L, other conditions are provided, too.  The list equally includes a statement like "soluble in acetic acid" -- so perhaps you do not need to decrease the pH value down to 1 (by HCl), and maybe you were able to obtain a sufficient concentration of epinephrine in a mixture of water / acetic acid, too?

Are there restrictions, imposed by the intended application / compatibility  toward (biological?) materials to stay near neutral conditions?  One way to reply to this and to tailor solubility of pharmaceutical active ingredients is to refrain from their form as free acids or bases, and to use them as salt.  In this sight, would be [epinephrine tartrate](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB3108435.htm), or an acetate, an alternative option?

Comment: Thank you so much for your consideration. the final concentration of Epinephrine is 23 mg/100mL. I can not use it as a salt and I have the biological measurement purpose.

Comment: @ghazi If your department has access to a database like Reaxys (by Elsevier) or Chemical Abstracts / scifinder scholar (by the American Chemical Society) to mention just two large ones relevant in (organic) chemistry, you may consider a substructure search.  Draw / insert the molecular structure of epinephrine / adrenaline, and *intentionally* allow the database to search for literature known salts.  Some of them will be more "inorganic", other more "organic" and maybe not interfering with your biological experiment intended.

Comment: I need to use florescence so I have to have the clear solution. maybe Acetic acid is a better idea.